# how to put a table of figures using \includegraphics?

Tags: tables, graphics, floats

I want to generate a 7x7 table, in each cell of the table is a figure.
The figure is Graph1, Graph2, ..., Graph49.

Currently i am using `\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{fig/Graph1} ...` manually put this line 49 times.

I am wondering is there any smart ways to do this?

Comment: With the `floatrow` package and the command `\foreach`, maybe?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to set up a loop to do this but a bit tricky inside a table and hard to make flexible if you decide you want to highlight row 3, or put a `\hline` between rows 6 and 7 or whatever. Instead I'd just use the tex macro system

```
\newcommand\myincl[2]{%
\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{fig/Graph\the\numexpr(#1-1)*7+#2\relax}}
```

depending if you want the order to go down or across you could switch round `#1` and `#2` in the definition.

then

```
\myincl{1}{1}&\myincl{1}{2}&\myincl{1}{3}&\myincl{1}{4}&\myincl{1}{5}&\myincl{1}{6}&\myincl{1}{7}\\
\myincl{2}{1}&\myincl{2}{2}&\myincl{2}{3}&\myincl{2}{4}&\myincl{2}{5}&\myincl{2}{6}&\myincl{2}{7}\\
\myincl{3}{1}&\myincl{3}{2}&\myincl{3}{3}&\myincl{3}{4}&\myincl{3}{5}&\myincl{3}{6}&\myincl{3}{7}\\
\myincl{4}{1}&\myincl{4}{2}&\myincl{4}{3}&\myincl{4}{4}&\myincl{4}{5}&\myincl{4}{6}&\myincl{4}{7}\\
\myincl{5}{1}&\myincl{5}{2}&\myincl{5}{3}&\myincl{5}{4}&\myincl{5}{5}&\myincl{5}{6}&\myincl{5}{7}\\
\myincl{6}{1}&\myincl{6}{2}&\myincl{6}{3}&\myincl{6}{4}&\myincl{6}{5}&\myincl{6}{6}&\myincl{6}{7}\\
\myincl{7}{1}&\myincl{7}{2}&\myincl{7}{3}&\myincl{7}{4}&\myincl{7}{5}&\myincl{7}{6}&\myincl{7}{7}
```